# Angular ui-view position

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's the demo:
http://www.tanadsplinare.com.hr/tmp/ngtest/ngVer/
(enter 1, 2 or 3 in search field then click on any item.)

Now the item details display in the `itemDetail` div on the right side.
However, the ui-view is placed in child partial view, in the left panel under the list, it is `itemsListDetailOutput` div.
I don't know other way, so I quickly copy the innerHTML of the ui-view to the itemDetail (where I want to display the item detail, but I can't apply ui-view to it because there is already other ui-view there and the item list uses it) and clear the innerHTML of the ui-view. I guess I should do it on digest event, but I don't know how to do it, so I just used `setTimeout`:

```
$('#itemDetail').hide();
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#itemDetail").html($("#itemsListDetailOutput").html()).fadeIn(200);
}, 10);
```

So basically:

1) is there other way to do it, the right way, instead of moving inner HTML to desired HTML element; and if there isn't:

2) how can I catch digest event to do it, instead of using setTimeout?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I've posted it to plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EC4FBr9RtTvaycBteLJ3 , have no idea why it doesn't work there, but the code is there. I'll post it here also:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>  

  <script src="lib/jquery-2.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

</head>
<body>
  <nav id="menu">
    <a href="index.html" class="selected">Angular way</a>
    <a href="../jsVer/index.html">JS way</a>
  </nav>

  <section>  
    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <nav class="itemsListHolder" ng-controller="ItemsListHolderController">
            <input ng-model="search" ng-change="searchUpdated(search)" type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />            
            <div ui-view id="itemsList"></div>
            enter 1, 2 or 3
        </nav>

        <div id="itemDetail" class="panel">Select the film from the list...</div>
    </div>    
  </section>

  <div id="preloader"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

/partials/ngItemsList.html:

```
<section ng-repeat="item in items">
<div class="itemsListItem" data-index="{{item.id}}" ng-click="displayDetail(item.id)">
    <div class="dataTitleOriginal">{{item.titleOriginal}}</div>
    <div class="dataTitleLocal">{{item.titleLocal}}</div>
    <div class="dataYear">{{item.year}}</div>
</div>
</section>
<div ui-view id="itemsListDetailOutput"></div>
```

/partials/ngItemDetail.html:

```
<div class="itemDetailName">Original Title</div>
<div class="itemDetailValue titleOriginal">{{titleOriginal}}</div>

<div class="itemDetailName">Local Title</div>
<div class="itemDetailValue titleLocal">{{titleLocal}}</div>

<div class="itemDetailName">Year</div>
<div class="itemDetailValue year">{{year}}</div>
```

/js/app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.controllers',
  'ui.router'
])

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('itemsList', {
            url: '/list/:query',
            templateUrl: 'partials/ngItemsList.html',
            controller: 'ItemListController'
        })
        .state('itemsList.itemDetail', {
            url: '/detail/:id',
            templateUrl: 'partials/ngItemDetail.html',
            controller: 'ItemDetailController'
        })
    ;
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
} ])
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'Main', 'Items', function($rootScope, $state, Main, Items) {
    Main.init();
    Items.initDatabase();
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
        document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
        }, 5000);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
        document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
    });
} ])
;
```

/js/services.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.factory('Main', function() {
    return {
        testdata: null,
        init: function() {
        }
    }
})

.factory('Items', function(Main) {
    var insertItem = function(permalink, titleOriginal, titleLocal, year) {
        var items = getItemsList();
        items.push({
            permalink: permalink,
            titleOriginal: titleOriginal,
            titleLocal: titleLocal,
            year: year
        });
        Main.testdata = items;
    };
    var initDatabase = function() {
        // Fill Database.
        if (!Main.testdata) {
            insertItem("1111-film", "1111 orig", "1111", "1980");
            insertItem("3333-film", "3333 orig", "3333", "1982");
        }
    };
    var getItemsList = function() {
        return (Main.testdata) ? Main.testdata : [];
    };
    var getItem = function(index) {
        var list = getItemsList();
        if (list && list.length && list.length > index) {
            return list[index];
        }
    };
    return {
        initDatabase: initDatabase,
        insertItem: insertItem,
        getItemsList: getItemsList,
        getItem: getItem
    }
})
;
```

/js/controllers.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('ItemsListHolderController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.searchUpdated = function(query) {
        $state.go('itemsList', {
            query: query
        });
    };
} ])
.controller('ItemListController', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Items', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, Items) {
    var query = $stateParams.query;
    var result = Items.getItemsList();
    var filteredResult = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i].titleOriginal.indexOf(query) > -1 || result[i].titleLocal.indexOf(query) > -1 || result[i].year.indexOf(query) > -1) {
            result[i].id = i;
            filteredResult.push(result[i]);
        }
    }
    $scope.items = filteredResult;
    $scope.displayDetail = function(index) {
        $state.go('itemsList.itemDetail', {
            id: index
        });
    };
} ])
.controller('ItemDetailController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Items', function($scope, $stateParams, Items) {
    var itemId = $stateParams.id;
    var item = Items.getItem(itemId);
    $scope.titleOriginal = item.titleOriginal;
    $scope.titleLocal = item.titleLocal;
    $scope.year = item.year;
    //xxxx UGLY FIX: display in ui-view, (it's set to display none anyway) and copy its innerHTML to another DOM element; also wait a while till digests
    $('#itemDetail').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#itemDetail").html($("#itemsListDetailOutput").html()).fadeIn(200);
    }, 10);
} ])
;
```

Comment: You might want to stop using jQuery when working with angularjs? Also, your demo provided as a plunker/fiddle would be that much more useful.

Comment: My question IS how to get rid of this dirty fix with jQuery and do it Angular way, please read it again. And I'm going to put it on plunker because it consists of several partials. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here is detailed [Nested View Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/riX8fA2TN7iTVer3Y6yj?p=preview) please check to understand nested views in ui.router...

**ANSWER**

ui.router supports nested view which you can use in this situation.

As you set details page as **child state** of list so you can put a `ui-view` in your **list html** and tell details state to include itself into that `ui-view`

syntax for nested views is a bit different than the normal state defination. Instead of directly define your **templateUrl** and **controller** you should define them in **views** property.

so firstly change your state defination with this one

```
views: {
    uiViewName@stateName: {
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: '...'
    }
}
```

so removing templateUrl and controller from your defination and put them into views property and you should set your stateName as well it is **itemsList** in your example...

Now you should add a ui-view with the name `uiViewName` (you can change it whatever you want) in your list html

```
...
<div ui-view="uiViewName"></div>
...
```

so whenever you go details page it will be injected that specific ui-view...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand; please look at my /js/app.js code. I changed view 'itemsList' to 'uiViewItemsList@itemsList' and 'itemsList.itemDetail' to 'uiViewItemDetail@itemDetail' and in index.html I applied ui-view="uiViewItemsList"  to the div itemsList, and I've applied ui-view="uiViewItemDetail" to the div itemDetail, but I've got error "invalid state name" or something like that...

Comment: After I've read your answer twice, I understand that you gave me what I already have - a nested view and finally ui-view in my list html. However, the point is, I want to have this ui-view in my index page (parent's parent page)! But I already have another ui-view there, for another purpose.

Comment: @Dalibor Don't you want to show both list and details at the same page?

Comment: @Dalibor you can inject that view any page... all you need to do is give a name for ui-view then define state that contains that ui-view... uiViewName@theStateUWant ...

Comment: I tried it, but I've got "State must have a valid name".

    $stateProvider
  .state('uiViewItemsList@itemsList', {
      url: '/list/:query',
      templateUrl: 'partials/ngItemsList.html',
      controller: 'ItemListController'
  })

Comment: and I added directive to the HTML element <div ui-view="uiViewItemsList" id="itemsList"></div>

Comment: In fact when I googled for that error, I see in the angular source code: if (!isString(name) || name.indexOf('@') >= 0) throw new Error("State must have a valid name");  The source is https://gist.github.com/prabirshrestha/7165107 ... 
so the state name shouldn't include @ or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, I see it now... I'm sure it will be helpful

Comment: By examining logic on your example I got it working. Thanks! Your plunker is the answer I was looking for but didn't see it at first

Comment: However, there is a little flaw with this solution: the detail item view is set to default when some other view is activated; what I want is that view to preserve the content when user browses other parts of page; Accordingly in your example what I want would be this: Click level4, and then level3 and level4 panel remains open.

Comment: I thought so, thank you. Then I would rather copy view's innerHTML to a destination element each time the view is updated. The question is when? I posted a question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758662/angular-event-for-digest-completed-and-view-updated